# joining external threads blender

Tags: python, multithreading, blender

The following code is supposed to create 2 threads. First 1, then after the other has finished the second.

```
import bpy
import os
import subprocess
import texturechange1
import texturechange2
import threading



#run texture changes and save files 
t1 = threading.Thread(target = texturechange1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target = texturechange2)
t1.start()
t1.join()
t2.start()
t2.join()
```

`texturechange1`and `texturechange2` are python scripts which change the texture of a given object and save the blender file.

They each have the command `bpy.ops.export.sketchfab()`, which creates a separate thread uploading to sketchfab.

The error is that, whereas `texturechange1`and `texturechange2` change texture and save their respective files, `texturechange2`is the only one uploaded to sketchfab. The given error for `texturechange1`is:

`please wait till current upload is finished`

Is there a way of applying `join()`to all threads created by the other threads?

Comment: Is this actually the code you're using? Passing a module as a target to `Thread` will not work properly. Are you really calling some function in `texturechange1` and `texturechange2`?

Comment: I thought of that too, however if i just replace the code it gives the same error. I want to be able to use thread on the function bpy.ops.export.sketchfab() such that the thread IT creates in the sketchfab addon is the one which is joined and correctly queued one after the other, does that make sense?

Comment: `texturechange1` and `texturechange2` aren't functions, though. They're modules. Using `threading.Thread(target=texturechange1)` will raise an exception about modules not being callable. Odds are your scripts are being executed when you import them. Put some print statements into your main code to see when each script is actually called.

Comment: `texturechange1`and `texturechange2`both run fine, and contain the function `bpy.ops.export.sketchfab()`. So the are callable. the problem is that the thread created by them to send the sketchfab model does not wait, or is not controlled by the thread syntax, do you know how to correct this?

Comment: i just checked, they are not being executed when i import them

Comment: correction they are not callable, you might be right, thanks dano i`ll have to work a bit more on this

Comment: Do you just have the called to `bpy.ops.export.sketchfab()` at the top-level of `texturechange1/2`? If so, that's going to be executed when you do `import texturechange1`.